# Merging partial duplicate cases without losing data

Tags: database, spss

I have a question in regards to preparing my dataset for research.

I have a dataset in SPSS 20 in long format as I am researching on individual level over multiple years. However some individuals were added twice to my dataset because there were differences in some variables matched to those individuals (5000 individuals with 25 variables per individual). I would like to merge those duplicates so that I can run my analysis over time. For those variables that differ between the duplicates I would like spss to make additional variables when all the duplicates are merged.

Is this at all possible and if yes HOW?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest following steps>

1. create auxiliary variable "PrimaryLast" with procedure Data->Identify Duplicate Cases by... , set "Define matching cases by" to your case ID
2. create 2 new auxiliary datasets with Data->Select Cases with condition "PrimaryLast = 0" and "PrimaryLast = 1" and selection "Copy selected cases to new dataset"
3. merge both auxiliary datasets with procedure Data -> Merge Files-> Add Variables, rename duplicated variable names in left box and move them in right box and select your case ID as key
4. don't forget to control if you made "full outer join", in case you lost non-duplicated cases and have only duplicated cases in your dataset, just merge datasets from step 2. in different order in step 3.

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer! What do you mean by full outer join? sorry just a student still learning the ropes of spss!

Comment: In step 2. you will create dataset with all IDs [PrimaryLast = 1] and dataset with subset of IDs [PrimaryLast = 0], therefore you have to select first dataset and use merge with second dataset.  

If you select second dataset and join it with first dataset you will lose cases with are not in second dataset.

Comment: my advice is work with syntax - https://www.spss-tutorials.com/spss-syntax-six-reasons-you-should-use-it/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
sort cases by caseID otherVar.
compute ind=1.
if $casenum>1 and caseID=lag(caseID) ind=lag(ind)+1.
casestovars /id=caseID /index=ind.
```

If a `caseID` is repeated more then once, after restructure there will be only one line for that case, while all the variables will be repeated with indexes.
If the order of the caseID repeats, replace the `otherVar` in the sort command with the corresponding variable (e.g. date). This way your new variables will also be indexed accordingly.

Comment: Thank you now I have a long format file in which I indeed did not lose information. However it is still not clear to me how I can change the variables and then restructure back to long format to do my analysis

Comment: It sounds like what you need now is varstocases, but you should post a new question with a complete description so you can get a full answer.